# Hashing Multiple Files

Tags: python, perl, bash, hash, batch-processing

> ### Problem Specification:
>
> Given a directory, I want to iterate through the directory and its non-hidden sub-directories,
>  and add a whirlpool hash into the non-hidden
> file's names.
> If the script is re-run it would would replace an old hash with a new one.
>
> > `<filename>.<extension>`   ==>  `<filename>.<a-whirlpool-hash>.<extension>`
> >
> > `<filename>.<old-hash>.<extension>`   ==>  `<filename>.<new-hash>.<extension>`

> ### Question:
>
> #### a) How would you do this?
>
> #### b) Out of the all methods available to you, what makes your method most suitable?

> ### Verdict:
>
> Thanks all, I have chosen SeigeX's answer for it's speed and portability.
> It is emprically quicker than the other bash variants,
>  and it worked without alteration on my Mac OS X machine.

Comment: Does it have to be a whirlpool hash or is that just an example?

Comment: Preferably Whirlpool as it is a strong cryptographic hash and is a public domain hash. Whirlpool can be installed by installing md5deep which installs whirlpooldeep also. I intend to use the hashcodes in implementing a freely distributed and open source p2p and file-management utility. I'm a C and Java coder who has done CompSci, unfortunately I tend to over-engineer because of this, and the simplest effective solution for this problem is outside the realm of my experience. :p

Comment: In one of your previous edits, you said you where thinking about this for a P2P app.  You probably don't want to rename users' files, so you could either save hashes in a database, or maybe use your current plan but make a hardlink farm instead of renaming the originals.

Comment: The solution provided in your question visits `'.*'` (hidden) directories. Is it desirable?

Comment: The solution doesn't work for files without extension (due to regexp that strips hashes from names).

Comment: I think your last revision broke it by not quoting properly; e.g. it should be find "${TARGET}".  Also, inside [[, $1 will be treated as a glob pattern, not a plain string.  Although even "*" doesn't match the empty string, so I guess it works.  I'll clean it up, though.

Comment: I count 5 sub-shells and 3 forks to other binaries which make this code quite inefficient; all of which can be eliminated btw.  Also as J.F. said, this does not properly handle file names with no extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated to fix:**

1. File names with '[' or ']' in their name (really, any character now. See comment)
2. Handling of md5sum when hashing a file with a backslash or newline in its name
3. Functionized hash-checking algo for modularity
4. Refactored hash-checking logic to remove double-negatives

```
#!/bin/bash
if (($# != 1)) || ! [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/directory"
    exit 1
fi

is_hash() {
 md5=${1##*.} # strip prefix
 [[ "$md5" == *[^[:xdigit:]]* || ${#md5} -lt 32 ]] && echo "$1" || echo "${1%.*}"
}

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    read hash junk < <(md5sum "$file")
    basename="${file##*/}"
    dirname="${file%/*}"
    pre_ext="${basename%.*}"
    ext="${basename:${#pre_ext}}"

    # File already hashed?
    pre_ext=$(is_hash "$pre_ext")
    ext=$(is_hash "$ext")

    mv "$file" "${dirname}/${pre_ext}.${hash}${ext}" 2> /dev/null

done < <(find "$1" -path "*/.*" -prune -o \( -type f -print0 \))
```

This code has the following benefits over other entries thus far

- **It is fully compliant with Bash versions 2.0.2 and beyond**
- No superfluous calls to other binaries like sed or grep; uses builtin parameter expansion instead
- Uses process substitution for 'find' instead of a pipe, no sub-shell is made this way
- Takes the directory to work on as an argument and does a sanity check on it
- Uses $() rather than `` notation for command substitution, the latter is deprecated
- Works with files with spaces
- Works with files with newlines
- Works with files with multiple extensions
- **Works with files with no extension**
- Does not traverse hidden directories
- **Does *NOT* skip pre-hashed files, it will recalculate the hash as per the spec**

#### Test Tree

```
$ tree -a a
a
|-- .hidden_dir
|   `-- foo
|-- b
|   `-- c.d
|       |-- f
|       |-- g.5236b1ab46088005ed3554940390c8a7.ext
|       |-- h.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|       |-- i.ext1.5236b1ab46088005ed3554940390c8a7.ext2
|       `-- j.ext1.ext2
|-- c.ext^Mnewline
|   |-- f
|   `-- g.with[or].ext
`-- f^Jnewline.ext

4 directories, 9 files
```

#### Result

```
$ tree -a a
a
|-- .hidden_dir
|   `-- foo
|-- b
|   `-- c.d
|       |-- f.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|       |-- g.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.ext
|       |-- h.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|       |-- i.ext1.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.ext2
|       `-- j.ext1.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.ext2
|-- c.ext^Mnewline
|   |-- f.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|   `-- g.with[or].d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.ext
`-- f^Jnewline.d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00.ext

4 directories, 9 files
```

Comment: You only need the -d check because you need the path to include a /, right?  Otherwise you could find "$@".  If there were bare filenames as part of that, though, you'd get dirname="$file".

Comment: I had 3 files with "[" or "]" in their filenames, and things went awry upon rehashing.

Comment: @_ande_turner_: Thanks for catching that. Give it another shot, I think you'll be pleasantly surprised.  I now use the offset parameter expansion to determine the extension, so the contents of the file name should no longer interfere.  I also fixed a problem with 'md5sum' putting a '\' in the hash if the file has a newline or a backslash.  This should now work with whatever you throw at it.

Comment: @Peter: No, I use the -d because if the user does not pass a directory as the argument, it is probably a mistake on their part. If this behavior is not desired, and you actually do want to run it on just one file, then you can safely remove '! [[ -d "$1" ]]' from the sanity check.

Comment: Very nice solution. I learned a lot of Bash tricks from reading this. Adding to bookmarks!

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
find -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    md5sum=`md5sum "${file}" | sed -r 's/ .*//'`
    filename=`echo "${file}" | sed -r 's/\.[^./]*$//'`
    extension="${file:${#filename}}"
    filename=`echo "${filename}" | sed -r 's/\.md5sum-[^.]+//'`
    if [[ "${file}" != "${filename}.md5sum-${md5sum}${extension}" ]]; then
        echo "Handling file: ${file}"
        mv "${file}" "${filename}.md5sum-${md5sum}${extension}"
    fi
done
```

- Tested on files containing spaces like 'a b'
- Tested on files containing multiple extensions like 'a.b.c'
- Tested with directories containing spaces and/or dots.
- Tested on files containing no extension inside directories containing dots, such as 'a.b/c'
- *Updated*: Now updates hashes if the file changes.

Key points:

- Use of `print0` piped to `while read -d $'\0'`, to correctly handle spaces in file names.
- md5sum can be replaced with your favourite hash function. The sed removes the first space and everything after it from the output of md5sum.
- The base filename is extracted using a regular expression that finds the last period that isn't followed by another slash (so that periods in directory names aren't counted as part of the extension).
- The extension is found by using a substring with starting index as the length of the base filename.

Comment: For your first version: `filename=${file%.*}` ... `extension=${file##$filename}` ... `echo mv "$file" "$filename.$md5sum$extension"`

Comment: I don't think your suggested change would help. It will fail for files without extensions in directories containing periods.

Comment: If not there then where directory names and filenames are similar.

Comment: This solution produces wrong filename on my test directory tree (for `'f^Jnewline.ext1'` file). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841737/bash-hashing-multiple-files-recursively/1842682#1842682

Comment: This solution also fails to follow the Spec because it never re-hashes an already hashed file.  If the file contents changes, the file needs to have its hash updated.

Comment: It followed the spec and more when I posted it. :) I think the spec must have changed.

Answer (score 3):

The logic of the requirements is complex enough to justify the use of Python instead of bash. It should provide a more readable, extensible, and maintainable solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hashlib, os

def ishash(h, size):
    """Whether `h` looks like hash's hex digest."""
    if len(h) == size: 
        try:
            int(h, 16) # whether h is a hex number
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith(".")] # skip hidden dirs
    for path in (os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if not f.startswith(".")):
        suffix = hash_ = "." + hashlib.md5(open(path).read()).hexdigest()
        hashsize = len(hash_) - 1
        # extract old hash from the name; add/replace the hash if needed
        barepath, ext = os.path.splitext(path) # ext may be empty
        if not ishash(ext[1:], hashsize):
            suffix += ext # add original extension
            barepath, oldhash = os.path.splitext(barepath) 
            if not ishash(oldhash[1:], hashsize):
               suffix = oldhash + suffix # preserve 2nd (not a hash) extension
        else: # ext looks like a hash
            oldhash = ext
        if hash_ != oldhash: # replace old hash by new one
           os.rename(path, barepath+suffix)
```

Here's a test directory tree. It contains:

- files without extension inside directories with a dot in their name
- filename which already has a hash in it (test on idempotency)
- filename with two extensions
- newlines in names

```
$ tree a
a
|-- b
|   `-- c.d
|       |-- f
|       |-- f.ext1.ext2
|       `-- g.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|-- c.ext^Mnewline
|   `-- f
`-- f^Jnewline.ext1

7 directories, 5 files
```

#### Result

```
$ tree a
a
|-- b
|   `-- c.d
|       |-- f.0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1
|       |-- f.ext1.614dd0e977becb4c6f7fa99e64549b12.ext2
|       `-- g.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
|-- c.ext^Mnewline
|   `-- f.0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1
`-- f^Jnewline.b6fe8bb902ca1b80aaa632b776d77f83.ext1

7 directories, 5 files
```

The solution works correctly for all cases.

---

Whirlpool hash is not in Python's stdlib, but there are both pure Python and C extensions that support it e.g., `python-mhash`.

To install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-mhash
```

To use it:

```
import mhash

print mhash.MHASH(mhash.MHASH_WHIRLPOOL, "text to hash here").hexdigest()
```

Output:
    cbdca4520cc5c131fc3a86109dd23fee2d7ff7be56636d398180178378944a4f41480b938608ae98da7eccbf39a4c79b83a8590c4cb1bace5bc638fc92b3e653

---

#### Invoking `whirlpooldeep` in Python

```
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, Popen

def getoutput(cmd):
    return Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]

hash_ = getoutput(["whirlpooldeep", "-q", path]).rstrip()
```

---

[`git`](http://git-scm.com/) can provide with leverage for the problems that need to track set of files based on their hashes.

Comment: Home again, home again, jiggidy-jig! Gooood Evening, J.F!

Comment: @_ande_turner_: 1. you can compile it from source http://labix.org/python-mhash 2. Use pure Python whirlpool.py http://www.bjrn.se/code/whirlpoolpy.txt `import whirlpool; print Whirlpool("text to hash").hexdigest()`

Comment: 3.Invoke `whirlpooldeep` from Python. I've added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't really happy with my first answer, since as I said there, this problem looks like it's best solved with perl.  You already said in one edit of your question that you have perl on the OS X machine you want to run this on, so I gave it a shot.

It's hard to get it all right in bash, i.e. avoiding any quoting problems with odd filenames, and behaving nicely with corner-case filenames.

So here it is in perl, a complete solution to your problem. It runs over all the files/directories listed on its command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# whirlpool-rename.pl
# 2009 Peter Cordes <peter@cordes.ca>.  Share and Enjoy!

use Fcntl;      # for O_BINARY
use File::Find;
use Digest::Whirlpool;

# find callback, called once per directory entry
# $_ is the base name of the file, and we are chdired to that directory.
sub whirlpool_rename {
    print "find: $_\n";
#    my @components = split /\.(?:[[:xdigit:]]{128})?/; # remove .hash while we're at it
    my @components = split /\.(?!\.|$)/, $_, -1; # -1 to not leave out trailing dots

    if (!$components[0] && $_ ne ".") { # hidden file/directory
        $File::Find::prune = 1;
        return;
    }

    # don't follow symlinks or process non-regular-files
    return if (-l $_ || ! -f _);

    my $digest;
    eval {
        sysopen(my $fh, $_, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY) or die "$!";
        $digest = Digest->new( 'Whirlpool' )->addfile($fh);
    };
    if ($@) {  # exception-catching structure from whirlpoolsum, distributed with Digest::Whirlpool.
        warn "whirlpool: couldn't hash $_: $!\n";
        return;
    }

    # strip old hashes from the name.  not done during split only in the interests of readability
    @components = grep { !/^[[:xdigit:]]{128}$/ }  @components;
    if ($#components == 0) {
        push @components, $digest->hexdigest;
    } else {
        my $ext = pop @components;
        push @components, $digest->hexdigest, $ext;
    }

    my $newname = join('.', @components);
    return if $_ eq $newname;
    print "rename  $_ ->  $newname\n";
    if (-e $newname) {
        warn "whirlpool: clobbering $newname\n";
        # maybe unlink $_ and return if $_ is older than $newname?
        # But you'd better check that $newname has the right contents then...
    }
    # This could be link instead of rename, but then you'd have to handle directories, and you can't make hardlinks across filesystems
    rename $_, $newname or warn "whirlpool: couldn't rename $_ -> $newname:  $!\n";
}


#main
$ARGV[0] = "." if !@ARGV;  # default to current directory
find({wanted => \&whirlpool_rename, no_chdir => 0}, @ARGV );
```

Advantages:
- actually uses whirlpool, so you can use this exact program directly.  (after installing libperl-digest-whirlpool).  Easy to change to any digest function you want, because instead of different programs with different output formats, you have the perl Digest common interface.

- implements all other requirements: ignore hidden files (and files under hidden directories).
- able to handle any possible filename without error or security problem.  (Several people got this right in their shell scripts).
- follows best practices for traversing a directory tree, by chdiring down into each directory (like my previous answer, with find -execdir).  This avoids problems with PATH_MAX, and with directories being renamed while you're running.
- clever handling of filenames that end with .  foo..txt... -> foo..hash.txt...
- Handles old filenames containing hashes already without renaming them and then renaming them back.  (It strips any sequence of 128 hex digits that's surrounded by "." characters.)  In the everything-correct case, no disk write activity happens, just reads of every file.  Your current solution runs mv twice in the already-correctly-named case, causing directory metadata writes.  And being slower, because that's two processes that have to be execced.
- efficient.  No programs are fork/execed, while most of the solutions that would actually work ended up having to sed something per-file.
  Digest::Whirlpool is implemented with a natively-compiled shared lib, so it's not slow pure-perl.  This should be faster than running a program on every file, esp. for small files.
- Perl supports UTF-8 strings, so filenames with non-ascii characters shouldn't be a problem.  (not sure if any multi-byte sequences in UTF-8 could include the byte that means ASCII '.' on its own.  If that is possible, then you need UTF-8 aware string handling.  sed doesn't know UTF-8.  Bash's glob expressions may.)
- easily extensible.  When you go to put this into a real program, and you want to handle more corner cases, you can do so quite easily.  e.g. decide what to do when you want to rename a file but the hash-named filename already exists.
- good error reporting.  Most shell scripts have this, though, by passing along errors from the progs they run.

Comment: I copied this into `~/whirlpool-rename.pl`, made it executable, moved into my test folder, ran it, and it returned 'invalid top directory at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/File/Find.pm line 593.'  I don't know how to check if the `libperl-digest-whirlpool` is installed.

Comment: put in a use Digest::Whirlpool; line.  It will fail at that point if you don't have the package.  In which case, you'll need to install it, probably using CPAN, or fink, if fink packages it.  (The cpan command works on OS X)

Comment: As for the "invalid top directory at /System/.../File/Find.pm", that happens when you run it without any args.  You're passing the empty list to find().  I forgot to make "." the default directory to recurse into.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: Ok, try the new version.  I also changed the use Digest;  to use Digest::Whirlpool, so it will fail if Digest doesn't have whirlpool.
And put in a comment about where you could link instead of rename.

Comment: Hmm, you could cp -al first, and then run this on the hardlink farm.  That loses the advantage of not writing to disk when nothing changes, though, and it's probably cleaner to just handle it in the perl script.

Comment: You could obviously parse the output of a whirlpool program for each file, if you can't get CPAN working.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -print | while read file
do
    hash=`$hashcommand "$file"`
    filename=${file%.*}
    extension=${file##*.}
    mv $file "$filename.$hash.$extension"
done
```

Comment: 1. Doesn't handle filenames with spaces, and 2. it will try to rename directories, which will cause it to not find the files within those directories...  Use **find . -type f -print|while read file** for the first line, then add quotes to the filenames on the **hash=** and **mv** lines.

Comment: Doesn't work for the reasons listed above, plus also doesn't work for files without extensions. I adapted your idea and made a new solution that fixes most of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to store the results in one file, like in

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > MD5SUMS
```

If you really want one file per hash:

```
find . -type f | while read f; do g=`md5sum $f` > $f.md5; done
```

or even

```
find . -type f | while read f; do g=`md5sum $f | awk '{print $1}'`; echo "$g $f"> $f-$g.md5; done
```

Answer (score 1):

In sh or bash, two versions. One limits itself to files with extensions...

```
hash () {
  #openssl md5 t.sh | sed -e 's/.* //'
  whirlpool "$f"
}

find . -type f -a -name '*.*' | while read f; do
  # remove the echo to run this for real
  echo mv "$f" "${f%.*}.whirlpool-`hash "$f"`.${f##*.}"
done
```

Testing...

```
...
mv ./bash-4.0/signames.h ./bash-4.0/signames.whirlpool-d71b117a822394a5b273ea6c0e3f4dc045b1098326d39864564f1046ab7bd9296d5533894626288265a1f70638ee3ecce1f6a22739b389ff7cb1fa48c76fa166.h
...
```

And this more complex version processes all plain files, with or without extensions, with or without spaces and odd characters, etc, etc...

```
hash () {
  #openssl md5 t.sh | sed -e 's/.* //'
  whirlpool "$f"
}

find . -type f | while read f; do
  name=${f##*/}
  case "$name" in
    *.*) extension=".${name##*.}" ;;
    *)   extension=   ;;
  esac
  # remove the echo to run this for real
  echo mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${name%.*}.whirlpool-`hash "$f"`$extension"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it, in bash.  Features: skips non-regular files; correctly deals with files with weird characters (i.e. spaces) in their names; deals with extensionless filenames; skips already-hashed files, so it can be run repeatedly (although if files are modified between runs, it adds the new hash rather than replacing the old one).  I wrote it using md5 -q as the hash function; you should be able to replace this with anything else, as long as it only outputs the hash, not something like filename => hash.

```
find -x . -type f -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d $'\000' file; do
    hash="$(md5 -q "$file")" # replace with your favorite hash function
    [[ "$file" == *."$hash" ]] && continue # skip files that already end in their hash
    dirname="$(dirname "$file")"
    basename="$(basename "$file")"
    base="${basename%.*}"
    [[ "$base" == *."$hash" ]] && continue # skip files that already end in hash + extension
    if [[ "$basename" == "$base" ]]; then
            extension=""
    else
            extension=".${basename##*.}"
    fi
    mv "$file" "$dirname/$base.$hash$extension"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

whirlpool isn't a very common hash.  You'll probably have to install a program to compute it.  e.g. Debian/Ubuntu include a "whirlpool" package.  The program prints the hash of one file by itself.  apt-cache search whirlpool  shows that some other packages support it, including the interesting md5deep.

Some of the earlier anwsers will fail on filenames with spaces in them.  If this is the case, but your files don't have any newlines in the filename, then you can safely use \n as a delimiter.

```
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS="
"
for i in $(find -type f); do echo "$i";done
#output
# ./base
# ./base2
# ./normal.ext
# ./trick.e "xt
# ./foo bar.dir ext/trick' (name "- }$foo.ext{}.ext2
IFS="$oldifs"
```

try without setting IFS to see why it matters.

I was going to try something with IFS="."; find -print0 | while read -a array,  to split on "." characters, but I normally never use array variables.  There's no easy way that I see in the man page to insert the hash as the second-last array index, and push down the last element (the file extension, if it had one.)  Any time bash array variables look interesting, I know it's time to do what I'm doing in perl instead!  See the gotchas for using read:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html#BADREAD0

I decided to use another technique I like: find -exec sh -c.  It's the safest, since you're not parsing filenames.

This should do the trick:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -type f -not -regex '.*\.[a-fA-F0-9]{128}.*'  \
-execdir bash -c 'for i in "${@#./}";do 
 hash=$(whirlpool "$i");
 ext=".${i##*.}"; base="${i%.*}";
 [ "$base" = "$i" ] && ext="";
 newname="$base.$hash$ext";
 echo "ext:$ext  $i -> $newname";
 false mv --no-clobber "$i" "$newname";done' \
dummy {} +
# take out the "false" before the mv, and optionally take out the echo.
# false ignores its arguments, so it's there so you can
# run this to see what will happen without actually renaming your files.
```

-execdir bash -c 'cmd' dummy {} +  has the dummy arg there because the first arg after the command becomes $0 in the shell's positional parameters, not part of "$@" that  for  loops over.  I use execdir instead of exec so I don't have to deal with directory names (or the possibility of exceeding PATH_MAX for nested dirs with long names, when the actual filenames are all short enough.)

-not -regex prevents this from being applied twice to the same file.  Although whirlpool is an extremely long hash, and mv says File name too long if I run it twice without that check. (on an XFS filesystem.)

Files with no extension get basename.hash.  I had to check specially to avoid appending a trailing ., or getting the basename as the extension.  ${@#./} strips out the leading ./ that find puts in front of every filename, so there is no "." in the whole string for files with no extension.

mv --no-clobber may be a GNU extension.  If you don't have GNU mv, do something else if you want to avoid deleting existing files (e.g. you run this once, some of the same file are added to the directory with their old names; you run it again.)  OTOH, if you want that behaviour, just take it out.

My solution should work even when filenames contain a newline (they can, you know!), or any other possible character.  It would be faster and easier in perl, but you asked for shell.

wallenborn's solution for making one file with all the checksums (instead of renaming the original) is pretty good, but inefficient. Don't run md5sum once per file, run it on as many files at once as will fit on its command line:

find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > dir.md5
or with GNU find, xargs is built in (note the + instead of ';')
 find dir -type f -exec md5sum {} + > dir.md5

if you just use find -print | xargs -d'\n',  you will be screwed up by file names with quote marks in them, so be careful.  If you don't know what files you might someday run this script on, always try to use print0 or -exec.  This is esp. true if filenames are supplied by untrusted users (i.e. could be an attack vector on your server.)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, interesting problem.

Try the following (the mktest function is just for testing -- TDD for bash! :)

Edit:

- Added support for whirlpool hashes.
- code cleanup
- better quoting of filenames
- changed array-syntax for test part-- should now work with most korn-like shells. Note that pdksh does not support :-based parameter expansion (or rather
  it means something else)

Note also that when in md5-mode it fails for filenames with whirlpool-like hashes, and
possibly vice-versa.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> #Tested with:
> # GNU bash, version 4.0.28(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> # ksh (AT&T Research) 93s+ 2008-01-31
> # mksh @(#)MIRBSD KSH R39 2009/08/01 Debian 39.1-4
> # Does not work with pdksh, dash
>
> DEFAULT_SUM="md5"
>
> #Takes a parameter, as root path
> # as well as an optional parameter, the hash function to use (md5 or wp for whirlpool).
> main()
> {
>   case $2 in
>     "wp")
>       export SUM="wp"
>       ;;
>     "md5")
>       export SUM="md5"
>       ;;
>     *)
>       export SUM=$DEFAULT_SUM
>       ;;
>   esac
>
>   # For all visible files in all visible subfolders, move the file
>   # to a name including the correct hash:
>   find $1 -type f -not -regex '.*/\..*' -exec $0 hashmove '{}' \;
> }
>
> # Given a file named in $1 with full path, calculate it's hash.
> # Output the filname, with the hash inserted before the extention
> # (if any) -- or:  replace an existing hash with the new one,
> # if a hash already exist.
> hashname_md5()
> {
>   pathname="$1"
>   full_hash=`md5sum "$pathname"`
>   hash=${full_hash:0:32}
>   filename=`basename "$pathname"`
>   prefix=${filename%%.*}
>   suffix=${filename#$prefix}
>
>   #If the suffix starts with something that looks like an md5sum,
>   #remove it:
>   suffix=`echo $suffix|sed -r 's/\.[a-z0-9]{32}//'`
>
>   echo "$prefix.$hash$suffix"
> }
>
> # Same as hashname_md5 -- but uses whirlpool hash.
> hashname_wp()
> {
>   pathname="$1"
>   hash=`whirlpool "$pathname"`
>   filename=`basename "$pathname"`
>   prefix=${filename%%.*}
>   suffix=${filename#$prefix}
>
>   #If the suffix starts with something that looks like an md5sum,
>   #remove it:
>   suffix=`echo $suffix|sed -r 's/\.[a-z0-9]{128}//'`
>
>   echo "$prefix.$hash$suffix"
> }
>
>
> #Given a filepath $1, move/rename it to a name including the filehash.
> # Try to replace an existing hash, an not move a file if no update is
> # needed.
> hashmove()
> {
>   pathname="$1"
>   filename=`basename "$pathname"`
>   path="${pathname%%/$filename}"
>
>   case $SUM in
>     "wp")
>       hashname=`hashname_wp "$pathname"`
>       ;;
>     "md5")
>       hashname=`hashname_md5 "$pathname"`
>       ;;
>     *)
>       echo "Unknown hash requested"
>       exit 1
>       ;;
>   esac
>
>   if [[ "$filename" != "$hashname" ]]
>   then
>       echo "renaming: $pathname => $path/$hashname"
>       mv "$pathname" "$path/$hashname"
>   else
>     echo "$pathname up to date"
>   fi
> }
>
> # Create som testdata under /tmp
> mktest()
> {
>   root_dir=$(tempfile)
>   rm "$root_dir"
>   mkdir "$root_dir"
>   i=0
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, no extention or spaces'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='.hidden'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='a hidden file'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test space'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, no extention, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, extention, no spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test.ab8e460eac3599549cfaa23a848635aa.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, With (wrong) md5sum, no spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test spaced.ab8e460eac3599549cfaa23a848635aa.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, With (wrong) md5sum, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test.8072ec03e95a26bb07d6e163c93593283fee032db7265a29e2430004eefda22ce096be3fa189e8988c6ad77a3154af76f582d7e84e3f319b798d369352a63c3d.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, With (wrong) whirlpoolhash, no spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test spaced.8072ec03e95a26bb07d6e163c93593283fee032db7265a29e2430004eefda22ce096be3fa189e8988c6ad77a3154af76f582d7e84e3f319b798d369352a63c3d.txt']
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, With (wrong) whirlpoolhash, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test space.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, extention, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test   multi-space  .txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, extention, multiple consequtive spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test space.h'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, short extention, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test space.reallylong'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, long extention, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='test space.reallyreallyreallylong.tst'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, long extention, double extention,
>                         might look like hash, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='utf8test1 - æeiaæå.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, extention, utf8 characters, spaces in name'
>
>   test_files[$((i++))]='utf8test1 - 漢字.txt'
>   test_files[$((i++))]='testfile, extention, Japanese utf8 characters, spaces in name'
>
>   for s in . sub1 sub2 sub1/sub3 .hidden_dir
>   do
>
>      #note -p not needed as we create dirs top-down
>      #fails for "." -- but the hack allows us to use a single loop
>      #for creating testdata in all dirs
>      mkdir $root_dir/$s
>      dir=$root_dir/$s
>
>      i=0
>      while [[ $i -lt ${#test_files[*]} ]]
>      do
>        filename=${test_files[$((i++))]}
>        echo ${test_files[$((i++))]} > "$dir/$filename"
>      done
>    done
>
>    echo "$root_dir"
> }
>
> # Run test, given a hash-type as first argument
> runtest()
> {
>   sum=$1
>
>   root_dir=$(mktest)
>
>   echo "created dir: $root_dir"
>   echo "Running first test with hashtype $sum:"
>   echo
>   main $root_dir $sum
>   echo
>   echo "Running second test:"
>   echo
>   main $root_dir $sum
>   echo "Updating all files:"
>
>   find $root_dir -type f | while read f
>   do
>     echo "more content" >> "$f"
>   done
>
>   echo
>   echo "Running final test:"
>   echo
>   main $root_dir $sum
>   #cleanup:
>   rm -r $root_dir
> }
>
> # Test md5 and whirlpool hashes on generated data.
> runtests()
> {
>   runtest md5
>   runtest wp
> }
>
> #For in order to be able to call the script recursively, without splitting off
> # functions to separate files:
> case "$1" in
>   'test')
>     runtests
>   ;;
>   'hashname')
>     hashname "$2"
>   ;;
>   'hashmove')
>     hashmove "$2"
>   ;;
>   'run')
>     main "$2" "$3"
>   ;;
>   *)
>     echo "Use with: $0 test - or if you just want to try it on a folder:"
>     echo "  $0 run path (implies md5)"
>     echo "  $0 run md5 path"
>     echo "  $0 run wp path"
>   ;;
> esac
> ```

Comment: In hashname(), your echo command doesn't quote any of the variables, so they're subject to word-splitting, and then echo joins its args with a single space.  So it won't work on filenames with repeated whitespace, or whitespace other than " ".

Comment: and you're using bash-specific features (maybe just the array in mktest), so you need to say #!/bin/bash (or with env, as you're already doing).

 Nice job on including a test dataset, though.

Comment: I've tested it with standard AT&T ksh (as packaged in Debian) --- and it works. I first thought you were wrong about the spaces -- but then I realized you meant consecutive spaces in names. That does indeed fail.

Comment: hm, the reason this worked seems to be that the non-standard declare-syntax is simply ignored (with warning) by ksh.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your updated question:

> If anyone can comment on how I can avoid looking in hidden directories with my BASH Script, it would be much appreciated.

You can avoid hidden directories with find by using

```
find -name '.?*' -prune -o \( -type f -print0 \)
```

`-name '.*' -prune`  will prune ".", and stop without doing anything. :/

I'd still recommend my Perl version, though.  I updated it...  You may still need to install Digest::Whirlpool from CPAN, though.

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841737/hashing-multiple-files/1880234#1880234

Answer (score 0):

using zsh:

```
$ ls
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

The magic:

```
$ FILES=**/*(.) 
$ # */ stupid syntax coloring thinks this is a comment
$ for f in $FILES; do hash=`md5sum $f | cut -f1 -d" "`; mv $f "$f:r.$hash.$f:e"; done
$ ls
a.60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3.txt
b.3b5d5c3712955042212316173ccf37be.txt
c.2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1.txt
```

Happy deconstruction!

Edit: added files in subdirectories and quotes around `mv` argument

Comment: He asked for subdirs, too.  Use **find . -type f -print|while read f**  in lieu of _for f in *_

Comment: Oh, and he may need to quote the file names to handle spaces.

Comment: @NVRAM zsh can glob for files in subdirectoires with `**/*(.)`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'digest/md5'

Dir.glob('**/*') do |f|
  next unless File.file? f
  next if /\.md5sum-[0-9a-f]{32}/ =~ f
  md5sum = Digest::MD5.file f
  newname = "%s/%s.md5sum-%s%s" %
    [File.dirname(f), File.basename(f,'.*'), md5sum, File.extname(f)]
  File.rename f, newname
end
```

Handles filenames that have spaces, no extension, and that have already been hashed.

Ignores hidden files and directories — add `File::FNM_DOTMATCH` as the second argument of `glob` if that's desired.